# Can't understand the solution of this combination

Tags: combinatorics

It's a journey with 9 people using two boats.

```
A boat can have maximum 7 people
B boat can have maximum 4 people
```

How many ways journeys can be done?

My solution:

```
A  B
7  2
6  3
5  4
```

So, number of ways= ${^7C_7}*{^4C_2} + {^7C_6}*{^4C_3} + {^7C_5}*{^4C_4}$ = 12+28+7=47

But in book i see the solution= ${^9C_7} + {^9C_6} + {^9C_5} = {^9C_2} + {^9C_3} + {^9C_4}$ = 246

Why?
Can anyone explain how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $7 \choose 7$ then you're assuming you're selecting $7$ out of $7,$ not $7$ out of $9.$ When you say $\binom{7}{7} \times \binom{4}{2},$ then you're assuming the order *within* the boat matters, which is not the case. I.e., $A=(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_7),B=(\color{red}{p_8}, \color{blue}{p_9})$ is the same as $A=(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_7),B=(\color{blue}{p_9}, \color{red}{p_8})$. So we don't count them twice.

---

How many ways can you choose $7$ out of $9$ people to ride boat $A$? If the $9$ people are labelled $p_1, p_2 \dots, p_9,$ then there are $\binom{9}{7}$ ways to do so:
$$ p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_7 \\
 p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_8 \\
p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_9 \\
p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6, p_7, p_8 \\
\dots $$
Note that every choice above completely defines the choice for $B.$ So the count for the first configuration $(A = 7, B = 2)$ is $9 \choose 7$.

Repeat for the other two configurations $(A = 6,B =  3)$ and $(A = 5, B =  4)$ to get ${9 \choose 7} +  {9 \choose 6}+ {9 \choose 5}$.

Comment: How do you format the mathematical equations and terms  like (9 7) or 9C7 or 9C2 when answering or asking mathematical related question ?

Comment: @newbie are you asking about [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)? This website uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render LaTeX code. LaTeX is a language for rendering math. You enclose the LaTeX code between `$   $`. The syntax of LaTeX is standard. You can see [this post here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) and [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559). Finally, here is a [link to](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) a (slow-loading) page listing MathJax supported commands.

Comment: On my Mac I can "control-click" on an entry to see what LaTeX code people have used in their posts (option "show Math as" and "TeX commands". This would be right-click on a PC I think?